Why does the .pvk file change when I back up the same certificate again?
I created a certificate in SQL Server like this
CREATE CERTIFICATE MY_CERT WITH SUBJECT = 'MY_CERTIFICATE'
GO

Then I backup up the certificate like this
BACKUP CERTIFICATE MY_CERT
TO FILE = 'C:\users\brubin\desktop\MY_CERT'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (file = 'C:\users\brubin\desktop\MY_CERT.pvk', ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '[password]')
GO

I ran the BACKUP CERTIFICATE command several times and compared the outputs.  Each time, the MY_CERT file's contents are the same, but the MY_CERT.pvk file is different.  What is changing in the .pvk file which is causing it to be different each time I back up the certificate?

There is a random salt used in .pvk encryption. Salt + password are used as key material for symmetric encryption key to be derived from.
